# Proxy for process run from golang

Tags: go, proxy

I have a Go app that runs multiple nodejs apps using os/exec module. I would like to capture all http requests from nodejs apps and their responses. How should I approach this in Go? I will know the url of server the nodejs apps will make requests to.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to answer. What kinds of "requests" do your nodejs apps make? What responses? Do you mean just the CLI arguments passed to them? Or do you mean something like doing a network capture of HTTP (or other network) requests?

Comment: Those are http requests, sorry I forgot it. The reason I want to do this is to be able to kind of record the apps including the data it gets from those HTTP requests.

Comment: So your Go app calls a Node app. That node app makes HTTP requests, and you want to capture them?  I don't think your Go app is related here. You either need the node app(s) to grab those captures, and dump them to a file or something, or you need an OS-level capture, i.e. with wireshark.  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are most probably right. I will use TShark as a solution.